# Blender display issue

Tags: interface

I have a problem with the display of Blender, why this doesn't appear correctly ?

[image]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Update your graphics drivers

Comment: Do you meet the minimal hardware and system requirements for Blender? https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/

Answer (score 0):

I have update my graphics drivers of my old graphic card NVIDIA :

I have downloaded this file https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/results/113161/#

- Log as root
- Download this file https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/results/113161/#
- cd /tmp
- chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.101.run
- ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.101.run

It's all good for not recent versions of Blender :

[image]